# How to make the <pre> code block interactive in React (see diagram)?

Tags: reactjs

I have a block of code inside a `<pre>` element which I need it to show the explanation of few key parameters when mouse over. For example, when mouse over `keyParameter` a mouse over event will be triggered.

```
render() {
  return (
  <pre>
   `{
     keyParameter: ''
   }`
  </pre>
)
```

My question how to add an event to `keyParameter` in this case when the entire code-block is in the string form.

My initial thought is to do some dirty DOM manipulations and add the event listener to the target `keyParameter`, however, I think there might be the "right" way to implement this feature via the **React** way.

Below is the effect I would like to achieve,

[image]
[image]

Comment: You'd do the same as without React: Wrap the key in a `<span>` and attach the event handler to that element. *"... and add the event listener to the target keyParameter"* You can only add event handlers to elements, not text. If you don't wrap `keyParameter` in its own element then you cannot bind an event handler to it - with or without React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at React's [`Synthetic Events`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events).

> onClick onContextMenu onDoubleClick onDrag onDragEnd onDragEnter
>   onDragExit onDragLeave onDragOver onDragStart onDrop onMouseDown
>   onMouseEnter onMouseLeave onMouseMove onMouseOut **onMouseOver** onMouseUp

You can attach any of these as props to your `<pre>` elements to attach a handler. So you would do something like:

```
<pre onMouseOver={e => {/* your event handler here */}>
  `{
     keyParameter: ''
   }`
</pre>
```

Comment: There is more than one parameter need to response the mouse over event and the explanation for different params are also not the same. Your approach will only trigger the mouse over event for the entire `<pre>` element